# Can I create an runtime-array with values somehow?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, collections, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to create a sidebar-menu that looks like this.

iOS
-entry1
-entry2
-entry3

Web
-entry1
-entry2

Other
-entry1
-entry2

Each "post" (as in - the files in the dir "_posts") will have one (or more) categories in the meta-data (at the top of the file) and is to be listed underneath that header in the menu. So for example, if I make a post which has got "categories: iOS" it should be listed under the "iOS" header in the menu.

```
      {% for cat in ["jekyll","ios","test"] %} // This is what I am unable to get right
        {% for post in site.posts %}
          {% if post.category == cat %}
            {{ post.categories }} // test
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Is it not possible to create an array on the fly like this? I am finding it really hard to google this specific question I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright to create an array on the current page I needed to use "front matter" i.e. the things on top of the pages surrounded by "---"

This is the solution:

Top of page:

```
---
cats: [1,2,3,asd]
---
```

Further down:

```
      {% for c in page.cats %}
        {{c}}<br/>
        #loop through more here. 
      {% endfor %}

</body>
```